# Javadoc lookup for GAE API in netbeans?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans, javadoc

Is anyone using netbeans 6.9 and Google AppEngine? If so do you have JavaDoc lookup working? Netbeans doesn't seem to be able to find the GAE JavaDoc even though I have tried adding the JavaDoc using the Java Platforms option, the libraries option and the server's option. I keep getting "JavaDoc not found" in the pop up window when doing a lookup. Hopefully someone knows how to resolve this issue.

PS I've also tried creating a new library and adding the JavaDoc but this did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the Google AppEngine plugin I had downloaded for netbeans and now the javadoc lookup works properly. So I guess that plugin was causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse IDE with the GAE plugin . Google supports it is kinda official development platform for GAE

Comment: I would but I'd prefer to use netbeans. I'd also like to know why this is happening.

Comment: yes i  too prefer netbeans but just for the sake of gae I use Eclipse.Also I do not know why that's happening . Does this help ? http://edu.netbeans.org/quicktour/javadoc.html . I could test it out but it's a big job cause I gotta import libraries and stuff as I have not used it before :)